# Using multiple runner annotation in test class for spring-boot and testrail

Tags: spring-boot, springjunit4classrunner, testrail

I have to link my tests with testrail and for that I have to use the testrailrunner. But if I exclude the springjunit runner then my tests fail on starting the service and its not possible to use both the runners

What's a workaround for this so that my tests get inititalize with the service beans and still logg in test rail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to have multiple test runners on single unit test, but use can use JUnit rules instead.

Spring introduces support for `@Rules` in 4.2 (4.2 RC1 is the latest version): https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7731

I am not familiar with `testrailrunner`, but if it has no support for JUnit rules, you can:

- implement custom rule for handling `testrail`
- implement your own runner that handles functionality from `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` and `testrailrunner`
- implement custom rule for injecting Spring context - there are some implementations that are supposed to work with current Spring version: http://www.alexecollins.com/tutorial-junit-rule/ (I haven't tested it).